# MDX Query: The Syntax for [Simple Cube] is incorrect

Tags: mdx

I'm pretty sure this is a syntax error, but I'm unfamiliar with MDX. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I keep getting the error "Parser: the syntax for [Simple Cube] in incorrect. The measure I'm using, [Cancel Disbursement Amount], returns three different values. I'm trying to select the value where the [Dim Disbursement Type] equals AGENT COMMISSION. Here's the query:

```
    SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Cancel Disbursement Amount] } 
    ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { [Dim Disbursement Type].[Description].&[AGENT 
    COMMISSION]} 
    ON COLUMNS FROM ([Simple Cube])
    CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, 
    FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME,  FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should remove the () :

```
... ON COLUMNS FROM [Simple Cube] CELL ...
```

Comment: Thank you. This actually did fix the syntax issue. Now I'm getting a "An MDX expression was expected while a full statement was specified" error. This is a calculated member I'm trying to add. Any ideas?

Comment: Better to ask a new question specific to : how defining a new calculated member.